# Angular Material Checkbox doesn´t change state of checked

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I´m working with a list of element and filtering the list using pipes, the filter is multi-selection to filter using more than one value, i save the filter in the localstorage to have persistent in the filter after close the window or reload the page, in the `mat-checkbox` component i use i function in the `[checked]="existInArray(color.id, filterColor)"` directive to check the checkbox if the value is already in the filter array to check the checkbox, but i have a problem, if the checkbox is checked using the function, the next time i click the checkbox to uncheck it, the checkbox doesnt change the state of `checked true to false`, only when i clicked a second time change to `checked false`

**Template**

```
<mat-checkbox *ngFor="let color of filterService.getFilter(filterType.FILTER_COLOR).items.ToArray() | filterQuery:filterOptions.color"
  [checked]="existInArray(color.id, filterColor)" class="filter-checkbox" [value]="color.id" [hidden]="color.id === '999999'"
  (click)="filterBy(filterType.FILTER_COLOR, color.id, filterColor)">
  <div class="assigned">
    <div class="assigned-avatar text-center" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': color?.color?.bgColor }"></div>
    <p class="assigned-name">{{ color.name }}</p>
  </div>
</mat-checkbox>
```

**Filter.ts**

```
  public existInArray(element, array: Array<string>): boolean {
    return array.indexOf(element) > -1;
  }

  public filterBy(filterType: FilterTypeEnum, element: any, array: Array<string>) {
    this.toggleInArray(element, array);
    this.updateFilterObservable(filterType);
  }
```

[image]

Example, as you can see in the image, the checkbox is already checked by default because i use the `existInArray` function to check if the value of the check already exist in the filter array, if i try uncheck it, the first time doesn´t work, but when i click a second time the checkbox is unchecked, any idea what could be....?

I think the reason is because the `[checked]` is trigger before i toggle the element from the array, but no idea so far idea how to solved.... any idea.

Comment: Stackblitz Example will help to dive in!

Comment: Yes sure, here you have a example of the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qabt5h

Comment: So you want to change the color of particular checkbox on check?

Comment: no if you can see, the first checkbox can be uncheck it on the first click

Comment: Bit more descriptive?

Comment: ok refresh the Stackblitz i made some change for you to see, as you can see im printing the `filterColor` array, so when you click any checkbox the status of check most change and the element will toggle on the `filterColor` array, but in this case the first click toggle the element on the array but not change the check status of the checkbox only on the second click the checkbox change the status

Comment: You want all checked items in that array and also check box should be checked?

Comment: Check the example in the code and look what happen, if you click any checkbox you can see that the checked status doesnt change, but the element is toggle into the array.

Comment: so what should happen is, when you click the checkbox the checked status most change and the item most toggle on the array.

Comment: have a look at:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qabt5h-axvpdu

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: no is not, did you check the example of the link and did you see where is the issue...?

Comment: It will be more complicated, If you clear your requirements to me then I can try!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale the OP wants to be able to pre-select the checkbox with the string array, and have the checkbox toggle without the extra click.

Comment: awww! Thanks, Marshal! @MiguelAngelFrias is that you want?

Comment: @MiguelAngelFrias have a look at:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qabt5h-jdlech

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a timing issue of your `[checked]="existInArray(color.id)"` being out of sync with your click event.... `[checked]="existInArray(color.id)"` happens before your click. Subscribe to the `change` event instead.

```
(change)="toggleInArray(color.id)"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Top_Select: any[]  = [];   // selection clear when selected... in your ts file

//on the check_click event firing add this make sure you get the index (index_chkbx) in the event

this.Top_Select[index_chkbx] = true;

in you html

Comment: to reset the check states just do 

this.Top_Select = this.Top_Select.filter(x => x !== x);